# Extracting complete forum data from a thread starter message with Discord.js 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I relativ new on discord.js with node. I'm trying to read the first message from a thread, I don't know, as an array and save it later. Since I would like to pass on the data later via an API.

I'm breaking my crown here.

i have experimented with:

```
const { ChannelType } = require('discord.js');

client.on('threadCreate', async (thread) => {
    if (thread.type == ChannelType.GuildPublicThread) {
        // When a new forum post is created
        console.log(thread.parentId) // The forum channel ID
        console.log(thread.id) // The forum post ID
        console.log(thread.name) // The name of the forum post
    }
})
```

but i con´t find a way to get the wohl thread data. Maybe someone can help me out with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const { ChannelType } = require('discord.js');

client.on('threadCreate', async (thread) => {
  if (thread.type === ChannelType.GuildPublicThread) {
    const messages = await thread.messages.fetch();
    const firstMessage = messages.first();

    // Access the data of the first message
    console.log(firstMessage.content); // Example: Log the content of the first message

    // You can save the necessary data from the first message for later use in your API
    const messageData = {
      content: firstMessage.content,
      author: firstMessage.author.tag,
      // Add more properties as needed
    };

    // Pass the messageData to your API or perform further operations
    // ...
  }
});
```

Try using this code.

Comment: Thanks i will call you lifesave :)
i think the
`const messages = await thread.messages.fetch();
 const firstMessage = messages.first(); ` has solved the problem. Also i have to do is fetch the thread, same as normal messages i think.

Comment: but i can´t accessing the data.
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content')``

Comment: It might be that there is no message in the thread or the bot doesn't have enough permission, you can check the client error by putting in this event listener.

client.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Discord Client Error:', error);
});